# Converting a string (delimited by consecutive delimiters) to rows using Oracle regular expression

Tags: oracle

I have a generic string delimited by consecutive delimiter tilde (~) in Oracle. For e.g. the string is 'apple~orange~~mango~~grapes'. It need to be converted into rows but one important thing to be noticed is that the separator is consecutive tilde not single tilde. The output should be like below:

apple~orange

mango

grapes

The workaround is already done using instr and substr oracle functions but I need more cleaner solution using Oracle regular expressins. I have tried using below query but not gettig the correct solution:

```
WITH str AS (SELECT 'apple~orange~~mango~~grapes' str FROM dual),
     cnt AS (SELECT LEVEL sno FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5)
SELECT regexp_substr (str, '[^~]+', 1, sno) FROM str CROSS JOIN cnt;
```

Comment: Do you have lookaheads? e.g. you could do the regex '1 or more any characters for which the lookahead `~~` fails'

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you can use any character like `*, ^, #` etc other than `,` if you expect any of your string will contain `,` as actual value):

```
WITH STR AS (SELECT REPLACE('apple~orange~~mango~~grapes','~~',',') STR FROM DUAL),
     CNT AS (SELECT LEVEL SNO FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (STR, '[^,]+', 1, SNO) FROM STR CROSS JOIN CNT;
```

You can also use XML with oracle

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT '"' 
             || REPLACE('apple~orange~~mango~~grapes','~~','","') 
             || '"' STR FROM DUAL)
select column_value str from cte, xmltable(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but delimiter cannot be less than two character i.e. ~~ and we cannot replace it to some other character. If delimeter can be of single character then the sql i have included in my query might had worked. This is because the data can contain any character and to ensure ensure that no delimiter should come as a data I am using two character delimiter.

Comment: @user2309418, are you 100% sure that your data will not contain two delimited characters in data itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select 
          t.str
         , regexp_substr (t.str, '[^~(?=~)]+', 1, rn) spl
    from YOURTABLE t
     cross
     join (select rownum rn
       from (select max (length (regexp_replace (t.str, '[^~~]+'))) + 1 mx
                     from YOURTABLE t
                  )
          connect by level <= mx
          )
   where regexp_substr (t.str,'[^~(?=~)]+' , 1, rn) is not null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but the sql you have pasted had already been tried. If you see my original question, the sql I used is almost same as you have provided. The only issue I am facing is that it's not returning the correct output based on two character delimiter.

Comment: I have modified answer, can you please check?

Comment: Hi, I have verified but still no success.